# Can nginx.conf access environment variables?

Tags: nginx, docker, environment-variables, kubernetes

I'm trying to run a docker container with nginx on a kubernetes cluster.  I'm using the environment variable service discovery for all my other containers, so I would like to keep it consistent and not have to bring something like skydns into the mix just because of this.  Is it possible to access environment variables in nginx such that I can tell it to proxy-pass to a kubernetes service?

Comment: [This serverfault question][1] should contain the answer to your question.


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf

Comment: That works but is rather hacky, I did see that, but I'm hoping there's a "kubernetes way" of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were tons of issues with doing the hacky HEREDOC, including it only having one time service discovery (not much better than hard coding). So my solution ended up being using confd to template nginx and restart nginx when the environment variables change. Here's the link to confd: https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd

Answer (score 1):

How about this the shell script below which is run by a Docker container?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/295bd3768d016a545d4a60cbb81a4983c2a26968/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/kibana-image/run_kibana_nginx.sh ?

Comment: Thanks, that does work, any chance you can condense your answers into a single answer so this is a little more organized?

Answer (score 0):

You mean use the value of an env var set in this way in a config file for nginx? One thing I have done in the past is to have a run.sh config script that is run by the Docker container which uses the env variable to effect substation in template file for an nginx config -- is that would you mean?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're saying, can you give an example? But to answer your question, yes I wish to use those environment variables in my nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping an included config file in the ConfigMap mounted as volume should work too.

You might need to change the config files' structure for that though.

Answer (score -1):

In the spec you can define an environment variable e.g.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kibana-logging
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/kibana:1.3
    livenessProbe:
      name: kibana-liveness
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 5601
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    env:
      - name: "ELASTICSEARCH_URL"
        value: "http://elasticsearch-logging:9200"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5601
      name: kibana-port
      protocol: TCP
```

This will cause the environment variable ELASTICSEARCH_URL to be set to http://elasticsearch-logging:9200. Will this work for you?

Cheers,

Satnam

Comment: No I know I could do that, it's using that environment envariable in nginx that I'm wondering about.